# Save Post and Add Post Meta Executing Twice

Tags: php, wordpress, function, hook

I'm trying to add or update two post meta on saving a post. Add if it's a new post and update if existing, but this function creates four in the database instead of two meta.

```
add_action( 'save_post',  'add_rewards');
global $WCFM, $WCFMmp;
function add_rewards ($product_id){
        if($product_id){
            $post_type = get_post_type($product_id);
            if($post_type == 'product'){
                $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
                $reg_price = $product->get_regular_price();
                $sal_price = $product->get_sale_price();
                $pric = $product->get_price();
                add_post_meta($product_id,'main_reward', $reg_price); 
                add_post_meta($product_id,'sub_reward', $sal_price); 
        }    
   }    
}
```

Comment: You should read the manual on `save_post` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/ note the third param.  Also, be aware that it's not uncommon for hooks to fire multiple times, thus using the correct conditions are important.

Comment: This looks so helpful, but I still don't get the right syntax to fix this issue. Can you help please? @HowardE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it explains in the `save_post` manual, you should use `save_post_{$post->post_type}` which minimizes the save_post calls on other post types. It's also a good idea to check for autosave.

Also, if you use `update_post_meta` instead of `add_post_meta` you'll end up with only one instance of each.  As it explains in the manual for that function, it says:

> If the meta field for the post does not exist, it will be added and its ID returned.
> Can be used in place of add_post_meta().

```
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'so71077799_add_rewards', 99, 1 );
function so71077799_add_rewards( $product_id ) {
    // Check to see if we are autosaving, if so, exit.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['_regular_price'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $product_id, 'main_reward', number_format( floatval( $_POST['_regular_price'] ), '2' ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['_sale_price'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $product_id, 'sub_reward', number_format( floatval( $_POST['_sale_price'] ), '2' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Howard. This adds the meta just once as I want BUT wouldn't insert the values until I update the product again.

Comment: Alright then, Actually, the above code works, but I have a long list of variables from which I get the values for the meta. They are within 'if' statements. Perhaps that's where the problem lies.

Comment: This works for both new posts and updates.